# Is there a log parser Java library?

Tags: java, parsing, templates, logging

I got a bunch of logs, each one with the following format:

```
10-20-2016 13:57:28 [main] ERROR com.project.Main:11 - Error message here
```

The template of this log is:

```
<date> <time> <method> <log_level> <class>:<line_no> - <message>
```

I want to parse that log and create a Java object with fields that match each token on that template.

I know that I can do this by hand, using a String Tokenizer, but I want to know first if there is some parsing library that already solves this problem (probably much better than I would do it).

I'm looking for something that supports that kind of templating: if I change the template, the parser should just extract those fields that match the template.

Comment: I don't think that you can solve everything with a library. The industry standard  for JEE is [Splunk](https://www.splunk.com/)

Comment: As this does not fit the format the internal java logging uses I am 98% sure there is no solution using something from the core libraries. There is probably some library out there that will solve your problem, but that's asking for a recommendation which is off-topic for StackOverflow as it's opinionated.

Comment: An OS analog for Splunk is Logstash

Comment: I know that but I want to know if there is even a third party library that does something similar to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Not with all of the attributes you've described actually.  Each logging framework ( log4j, logback, JUL are the big 3 ) have different configuration semantics so any solution would be specific to the backend in question.

Most of them have some sort of [LogEvent](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LogEvent.html) object or something that exists in the form you want as it get's passed through the pipeline before it ends in a file or whatever.

Figure out which logging back end you are using and just add an appender that serializes that thing to an [ObjectOputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and read it later at your leisure.

Answer (score 1):

You're barking up the wrong tree here entirely. The idea is to install a handler that receives data according to the logging API you are using, and do with that data whatever you wish. Parsing logger output is doomed to failure sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

What works for a lot of cases is just making sure the logs are coming in a structured format.

If they come from outside you can pass them through [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/) and keep the most of the structure available. If you are using Logback or log4j there are libraries that can help with that such as [logback-more-appenders](https://github.com/sndyuk/logback-more-appenders)

This does not solve all cases though and sometimes even the structured logs still have the message that could use some parsing to extract values. In such case you need to write a custom parser... or use a dedicated solution that will do its best at figuring out what is the log pattern and extract parameters: https://www.logsense.com/blog/integrating-java-logs-with-logsense (disclaimer, I am working on it)